# Mac: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "QApplication::palette()", referenced from:

Tags: macos, qt

i am getting the following linker error when compiling our Qt project.
We do not use qmake. We use autoconf & automake..
Now porting to Mac brings the follwoing error:
I have tried using Qt-SDK and by compiling Qt by myself... Neither worked :(

Maybe somebody has an idea?

```
    /bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link clang++  -g -O2  -Wl,-rpath - 

    Wl,/space/dev-libs/instantclient_10_2  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/space/dev-libs/boost_1_53/lib -v  -o showtime showtime-application_resources.o showtime-main.o cmdline.o ../../atcaf/atcafgui/libatcafgui.la 
libtool: link: clang++ -g -O2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/space/dev-libs/instantclient_10_2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/space/dev-libs/boost_1_53/lib -v -o showtime showtime-application_resources.o showtime-main.o cmdline.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  ../../atcaf/atcafgui/.libs/libatcafgui.a -L/usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Widgets.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Gui.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Sql.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Xml.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5XmlPatterns.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Network.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Core.dylib -L/space/dev-libs/log4cxx-dfs/lib /space/dev-libs/log4cxx-dfs/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib -L/usr/lib -laprutil-1 -lexpat -liconv -lpq -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -lapr-1 -lpthread -L/space/dev-libs/boost_1_53/lib -lboost_python -lpython2.6 -L/space/dev-libs/instantclient_10_2 -lclntsh -lz
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.7.4 -o showtime -lcrt1.10.6.o -L/usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib -L/space/dev-libs/log4cxx-dfs/lib -L/usr/lib -L/space/dev-libs/boost_1_53/lib -L/space/dev-libs/instantclient_10_2 -rpath /space/dev-libs/instantclient_10_2 -rpath /space/dev-libs/boost_1_53/lib showtime-application_resources.o showtime-main.o cmdline.o -bind_at_load ../../atcaf/atcafgui/.libs/libatcafgui.a /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Widgets.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Gui.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Sql.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Xml.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5XmlPatterns.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Network.dylib /usr/local/Qt-5.0.1/lib/libQt5Core.dylib /space/dev-libs/log4cxx-dfs/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib -laprutil-1 -lexpat -liconv -lpq -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -lapr-1 -lpthread -lboost_python -lpython2.6 -lclntsh -lz -lstdc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "QApplication::palette()", referenced from:
      _main in showtime-main.o
  "QApplication::commitData(QSessionManager&)", referenced from:
      vtable for Application in libatcafgui.a(libatcafgui_la-Application.o)
  "QApplication::saveState(QSessionManager&)", referenced from:
      vtable for Application in libatcafgui.a(libatcafgui_la-Application.o)
  "QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(QModelIndex const&, QModelIndex const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for LogTableWWU in libatcafgui.a(libatcafgui_la-moc_LogTableWWU.o)
  "QWidget::styleChange(QStyle&)", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when porting from Qt 4 to Qt 5. There were missing functions for `QApplication::commitData()` and `QApplication::saveState()`.

I had derived a class from `QApplication`, in the header file I changed

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

to

```
#include <QApplication>
```

and this solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this error was driving me insane! Worst part was, that the sub-project that containted the files with the <QWidgets/...> compiled on it's own, but every project including the library threw the same errors!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although mine was related to QWidget functions (e.g. *QWidget::styleChange(QStyle&)* or *QWidget::fontChange(QFont const&)*) rather than QApplication.

As suggested by **koan**, I looked for all the occurrences of

```
#include <QtGui/
```

in my project and replaced them with

```
#include <
```

which solved the problem. I tested this with both clang and g++ versions (5.0.1 and 5.0.2) and they both seem to work.

**Note:**

A number of solutions found on the web proposed to add

```
QT += widgets
```

to the qmake project (.pro) file, as this might be related to an existing bug. While I don't think that adding this is a problem, it did not solve this specific issue.

Comment: He's using Qt 5 so he must use QT += widgets if he's using widgets.